# does a positive/negative number cancel itself?

Tags: functions

By positive negative I mean the function that looks like an addition sign $(+)$ with a subtraction sign $(-)$ right underneath it.

does a positive/negative number cancel itself? As in $x$ positive/negative 3.

wouldn't that written out look like $x-3+3$? Wouldn't the three's would cancel, therefore liberating the need to do the work out for a more complicated math problem?

Comment: If you mean $x\pm 3$, this is a shorthand for two expressions $x+3$ and $x-3$. For example, the two equations $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ can be summarized as $(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm 2ab+b^2$. There is no cancellation, i.e. this summary cannot be simplified to $(a+0)^2=a^2+0+b^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x\pm 3$ means $x+3$ or $x-3$ not $x+3-3$, so the $\pm$ doesn't cancel. Are you thinking about simplifying the quadratic formula perhaps?